# How to login to mutiple servers in a loop

Tags: linux, shell-script, shell

I have a script called script.sh. I want to execute it on various machines like host1, host2 etc. How to loop each server by passing user name and password ?

Comment: Do you want to run it in parallel or sequentially ?

Comment: Please see Ansible. It is built for this. https://www.ansible.com/overview/how-ansible-works

Comment: See Ansible/Salt Stack/Puppet/Chef well any orchestrator that is able able to run scripts/ program/ensure/configuration.... Those are the real tool to use.

Answer (score 2):

Looping through a bunch of servers that don't have keys on would require looping through a file with your passwords either in plaintext, or a simple encryption. I'd highly recommend against doing that personally, especially if it's in a production environment.

---

### Warning - I do not recommend this

A quick and dirty solution could be done with `sshpass`, and a text file containing your server hostnames, with their passwords:

serverList.txt example:

```
server1 password1
server2 password2
```

*really* unsafe script example:

```
for host in $(awk '{print $1}' serverList.txt); do
    password=$(grep -w "$host" serverList.txt | awk '{print $2}')
    sshpass -p "$password" ssh $host < ./script.sh
done
```

---

### This is what I recommend:

If this is something you'd need to do regularly, I'd recommend looking into `dsh` (distributed shell).

#### Installation

Installing it from Debian/Ubuntu is easy:

```
sudo apt-get install dsh
```

for RHEL based distros, you'll have to compile `libdshconfig` first, then `dsh`:

```
# libdshconfig
wget http://www.netfort.gr.jp/~dancer/software/downloads/libdshconfig-0.20.10.cvs.1.tar.gz
tar xfz libdshconfig*.tar.gz 
cd libdshconfig-*
./configure ; make
make install

# dsh
wget http://www.netfort.gr.jp/~dancer/software/downloads/dsh-0.22.0.tar.gz
tar xfz dsh-0.22.0.tar.gz
cd dsh-*
./configure ; make 
make install
```

#### Configuration

The config for `dsh` will by default use `rsh` as it's login protocol. You'll probably want to change that to `ssh` as `rsh` is unencrypted.

if installed via `apt`, the config file will be `/etc/dsh/dsh.conf` - if you've had to compile it for RHEL based distros, then the config file will be `/usr/local/etc/dsh.conf`

update this:

```
remoteshell =rsh
```

to this:

```
remoteshell =ssh
```

once you've done that, you'll want a list of machines you'll want to run things on. For debian, this file will be `/etc/dsh/machines.list`, for RHEL it will be `/usr/local/etc/dsh/machines.list`

The format of the list can be either hostname, IP or FQDNs separated by a new line. For example, this would be a valid `machines.list` file, provided all the hostnames or FQDNs resolve:

```
10.20.30.40
10.20.30.31
server1.stackexchange.com
server2
root@myOtherServer
```

#### Examples

At this point, you can now run commands sequentially or in parallel on your multiple hosts in `machines.list`

Sequentially, with only the return output:

`dsh -a <command>`

```
$ dsh -a echo hello
hello
hello
```

print each hostname as a prefix to its corresponding output:

`dsh -a -M <command>`

```
$ dsh -a -M echo hello
root@server1: hello
root@server2: hello
```

do the same, but rather than sequentially, run the command concurrently:

`dsh -aMc <command>`

only use select hosts:

`dsh -Mc -m <host1> -m <host2> <command>`

#### Caveats

So the problem with this in your scenario is that you would require ssh keys setting up (unless you're happy to enter the password for each host), and you would also need the script on each of the hosts.

I'd personally say this would be the best and most secure way to run it anyway depending on the size of the script, as you don't have to pass the script over ssh for each host, they all can run the script locally.

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to run the script on several machines, you will be better using `parallel`, a tool to do exactly what you want.

See a tutorial [here](https://www.cyberciti.biz/cloud-computing/how-to-use-pssh-parallel-ssh-program-on-linux-unix/) and [here](https://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/13556/run-a-script-in-parrallel-over-ssh).

Comment: It would be better if you actually also showed how to solve the issue.

Comment: @Kusalananda, you mean by preparing a complete example, based on some hypothetical host list?  I have edited the question with a commandlinefu link. Not sure if this is enough...

Comment: Edit your answer to show an exmaple that would be the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ssh` it is really simple and most sysadmin always use it.
Lets suppose in this example there are 3 remote hosts and 1 active host. The active is called `host1`, and the others are `host2`, `host3` and `host4`. And the username are the same on every hosts that is `user1`.

**Generate ssh key pair** (just press enter until back to shell):

```
user1@host1$ ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

**Deploy the public key** to the `host2`, `host3` and `host4`:

```
user1@host1$ for i in {2..4}; do ssh-copy-id user1@host$i;done
user1@host2 password:
user1@host3 password:
user1@host4 password:
```

**Pass the script** from `host1`:

```
user1@host1$ for i in {2..4}; do scp script.sh user1@host$i:/home/user1 ;done
```

**Run the script** from `host1`:

```
user1@host1$ for i in {2..4}; do ssh user1@host$i 'sh script.sh'; done
```